# Transform: scale vertically aligned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, transform

I have `div` elements vertically aligned within other `div` elements.

I am aligning them using: `position: relative; transform: translateY(-50%); top: 50%`. That works fine.

I now want to scale the elements (using the jQuery plugin 'Transit').

When I scale the child `div` elements, they move out of vertical alignment (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUxzL.png second green box has `transform: scale(1.5)` applied).

Is there any way around this?

Comment: can you show your code !?

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you're forgetting that the second `transform` will **completely overwrite** the original one. The second transform should be **both** `transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1.5);`

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: .25em;
}

.box {
  height: 2em;
  width: 3em;
  background: limegreen;
  float: left;
  margin: .5em;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.tall {
  height: 4em;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box tall"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

Frankly though, that alignment technique is not necessary. These children could be aligned much simpler using `display:inline-block` with `vertical-align:middle` or just flexbox and `align-items:center`

**Inline-block**

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: .25em;
}

.box {
  height: 2em;
  width: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: limegreen;
  margin: .5em;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.tall {
  height: 4em;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box tall"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

**Flexbox**

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: .25em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  height: 2em;
  width: 3em;
  background: limegreen;
  margin: .5em;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.tall {
  height: 4em;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box tall"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```